# Checkout a file to previous commit using libgit2sharp

Tags: libgit2sharp

i have committed a file. now i want to revert the file to one of the previous commit as we do $git checkout sha filepath. i want to realize this command with libgit2sharp.
Can any body tell me the example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

public void RevertToSpecificVersion()
        {

```
        using (var repo = new Repository(@"C:\Users\insiv1\source\GitRevert"))
        {

            foreach (LogEntry entry in repo.Commits.QueryBy("ArchitectureDocs.txt").ToList())
            {
                if (entry.Commit.Id.ToString().Equals("25c20851cfef37492fd008b969408dc730ae7b6b"))
                {
                    Commands.Checkout(repo, entry.Commit);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```